# Normalization vs Scaling for not normal distribution in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scale, normalize

In my university project, I'm given data that has various ranges of values also not normal distribution. I already read the documentation of function of [sklearn normalization](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-normalization) it said normalization is a process of scaling individual samples to have unit norm. Also in sklearn there are `Normalization` and `StandardScaler` they seemed to have same function that is to scale the data. But then I read [this article](https://medium.com/@nsethi610/data-cleaning-scale-and-normalize-data-4a7c781dd628) telling the differences between scaling and normalization distinguishing between them by saying that **Normalization is the way for you to reach normal distribution** and **Scaling is the way for you to range you data**.

1. Why does sklearn Normalization function has the same function of StandardScaler if both supposed to do different thing to the data?
2. Does it mean by scaling we could reach normal distribution and scaling is actually one of the way to normalize distribution?
3. For my case if I have various ranges of values and not normal distribution, if Normalize and Scaling is different thing then it means I have to scale **and** to normalize my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) has different meanings depending on the context  and sometimes the term is misleading.
I think sklearn uses the terms interchangeably, to mean *adjusting values measured on different scales to a notionally common scale* (e.g., between 0 and 1), rather than change the data such that they follow a Normal distribution (apart from the StandardScaler, which does that).

From my understanding, in sklearn they differ in the input they work on and how, and where they can be used.

I assume that with `Normalization` you mean `sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer`.

So, the main difference is that `sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer` scales **samples** to unit norm (vector lenght) while `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` scales **features** to unit variance, after subtracting the mean.
Therefore, the former works on the **rows**, while the latter on the **columns**.

In particular,

1. `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` ["scales input vectors individually to unit norm (vector length).'](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.normalize). It can either be applied to rows (by setting the parameter `axis` to 1) and to features/columns (by setting the parameter `axis` to 0). It uses one of the following norms: `l1`, `l2`, or `max` to normalize each non zero sample (or each non-zero feature if the axis is 0).
   **Note:** The term *norm* here refers to the mathematical definition. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221934/what-does-this-statement-unit-l2-norm-mean) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) for more information.
2. `sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer` ["normalizes samples individually to unit norm."](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer). It behaves exactly as `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` when `axis=1`. Differently from `normalize`, `Normalizer` performs normalization using the Transformer API (e.g. as part of a preprocessing sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline).
3. `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` ["standardizes features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance"](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html). It does not use the norm of a vector, rather it computes the z-score for each feature.

This interesting [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/scale-standardize-or-normalize-with-scikit-learn-6ccc7d176a02) explore more the differences among them.

Let's use `norm='max'` for convenience:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize, Normalizer, StandardScaler

X = [[1, 2],
     [2, 4]]

# Normalize column based on the maximum of each column (x/max(column))
normalize(X, norm='max', axis=0)

# Normalize column based on the maximum of each row (x/max(row))
normalize(X, norm='max', axis=1)

# Normalize with Normalizer (only rows)
Normalizer(norm='max').fit_transform(X)

# Standardize with StandardScaler (only columns)
StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)


from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('normalization_step', normalize())] # NOT POSSIBLE

pipe = Pipeline([('normalization_step', Normalizer())] # POSSIBLE

pipe = Pipeline([('normalization_step', StandardScaler())] # POSSIBLE

pipe.score(X, y) # Assuming y exists
```

The aforementioned lines of code would transform the data as follows:

```
# Normalize with normalize, axis=0 (columns)
[[0.5, 0.5],
 [1. , 1. ]]

# Normalize with normalize, axis=1 (rows)
[[0.5, 1],
 [0.5, 1. ]]

# Normalize with Normalizer (rows)
[[0.5, 1],
 [0.5, 1. ]]

# Standardize with StandardScaler (columns)
[[-1, -1],
 [1, 1. ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

"rather than change the data such that they follow a Normal distribution (apart from the StandardScaler, which does that)."

this is not true - the standard scaler just scales the data by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. It does not somehow change the shape of the data distribution.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't forget to either: turn this answer into a comment when you get commenting privilege/ or make it a full answer as in [answer]